# Django Form with a one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form in Django called `PersonForm` this forms model has a **one-to-many relationship** with Car. When displaying the PersonForm just like in the Django Admin I would like to allow my users to select/deselect from a list of Cars etc. Is this possible? I'm looking for information on where to start.

This is what I have so far for the PersonForm:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('description',)
```

**The Models:**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length="150")



class Car(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length="25")
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Person', related_name="Car")
```

So in the person form I need to show a list of cars that person is the owner of an allow selecting/deselecting of them. I'm assuming I can do this in the form i.e. using something like the related name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like  you want [an inline model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects). This give you the ability to add/remove Car objects from a Person within the Person form.

That previous link was for inlinemodeladmin.  This next link is for an inline form:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelforms-factory

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have any chance with inline formset, so i would suggest to override your save method of the model, i feel it's more DRY:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # add a field to select a car
    car = forms.ModelChoiceField(car.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('description', 'car')

     def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit)
        # set Car reverse foreign key from the Person model
        instance.car_set.add(self.cleaned_data['car']))
        return instance
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but since I found myself almost exclusively pointed here by google when searching, I thought I would include the following for anyone else looking for an answer.

The answer, I think, is to use

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

or

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield

There is a good article on how to use the modelmultiplechoicefield at :

https://medium.com/swlh/django-forms-for-many-to-many-fields-d977dec4b024

But it works for one to many fields as well.  These allow us to generate a form with multiple choices as checkboxes or similar widgets based upon a related field in a model.